# Getting lost quickly with Views and Controllers

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am coming from a Windows Visual Studio (VS) background, so I'm finding the Xcode environment, well, overly complex for lack of a better description.

I'm planning an app which will need 4 views (what I would call windows in VS).
1) The main (starting) view would have a Toolbar at the bottom which opens any of 3 views.
2) View A would have a Nav bar at the top for "Cancel" and "Done" which would return to Main.
3) View B would have a Nav bar at the top for "Back" which would return to Main
4) View C would have no Nav bar but would return to Main using a DoubleTap.

I'm finding it very confusing to piece this together without a straightforward example.

Where can I find some clear explanations of Views vs Controllers, what they're each used for, and how to use them, preferably with examples/tutorials/etc?

Online is best, books are fine.
I'm using Xcode 4.2, no storyboards (for ios 4.2 compatibility).

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best book / resources for learning iOS programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming)

Comment: Almost (some good info too) - I'm not looking for Objective-C help. I'm looking for documentation on the structures and usage. For example, why is there a Nav Bar and a Nav Bar Controller? What do they each do and why do you need both? That kind of stuff...

Comment: The answers to that question cover much more than just Objective-C.

Comment: Also, note that the question I linked was closed as "not constructive".  This question ought to be closed on the same grounds, but I thought it would be more helpful to you to close it as "exact duplicate" of that question.

Comment: Fair enough - how do I close it as exact dupe?

Comment: Online Tut:                                 http://www.iosdevnotes.com/tag/navigation-controller/

Comment: For the simplest approach, forget about views and just use view controllers, with one view controller per "window", and generally using a UINavigationController to be the "ringmaster".

Comment: These books are going to be gibberish if you don't understand the terminology used commonly in Cocoa. Start with the Human Interface Guidelines for iOS. When you're done reading it, read it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general distinction between view controllers and view is something that you can understand  independently of Xcode/Cocoa - it's a design pattern called MVC (Model, View, Controller).

In MVC, your application structure is split into 3 layers:

1) The model is your data layer, such as files, databases, network services, and objects that exist independently of the display such as a user.

2) The view is what you see on screen. A view is often composed of several sub views in a hierarchy, for example a window (which is a type of view) contains a toolbar (another type of view) and some buttons (each a view), labels, text fields, etc. These are all views.

3) The controller, aka view controller is the glue that connects these two together. A user object for example has no idea how to display itself, and a label has no knowledge of a user object, so it is the job of the view controller to tell a particular label to display the name of a particular user. Similarly when you type text into a text field, the text field doesn't know that text is a password, so it's the job of the controller to take that text and store it in the correct place, or submit it to the correct web service, or whatever.

So basically a controller converts your model data into the right format to display within your views, and handles feedback from your views (a button press, a text entry, etc) and modifies your model accordingly.

In cocoa every view controller owns a main view (it's "view" property) and may also manage the subviews of that view such as buttons, labels, etc.

Normally there is one view controller class per screen of your app. Occasionally parts of your screen that have standard behaviours are managed by other view controllers.

So for example the navbar is managed by something called a navigation controller. A navigation controller actually manages a stack of view controllers as well as the navigation bar view itself. When you push or pop a view controller onto the navigation controller stack, it makes sure that the view from the current view controller gets displayed and that the navbar shows the correct title. When you tap the back button in the navbar view, the navigation controller receives that button event and pops the current view controller (and it's associated view) off the stack.

The advantage of this approach (MVC) is that is massively cuts down on the amount of subclassing you need to do. Every button on your screen is probably just an instance of a standard UIButton object. You don't need to subclass each button just to change it's behaviour because the button doesn't need to know anything about what happens when it is pressed, it just delegates that press to the view controller to manage.

Generally, you rarely need to create custom view subclasses. Almost all of your application can be built by arranging standard views on a screen and managing them with a custom view controller subclass.

Nibs/xibs are particularly useful for this because they let you visually lay out your views and visually bind their actions (e.g. button taps) to methods on your view controller using drag a drop. This saves you filling up your view controller with pointless layout code (create a button with these coordinates and this colour and attach it to this subview, etc). Unfortunately nibs can be confusing for new developers because they hide a lot of what is going on behind the scenes.

For multi-screen apps, iOS provides a set of so-called container controllers, which are controllers that manage multiple sub-controllers. UITabBarController and UINavigationController are the main examples. UITabBarController is good if you have several screens that you want to tab between, UINavigationController is good if you have a hierarchy of screens that the user can go back and forth between like a browser.

Comment: Since you were kind enough to answer, let me see if I understand the concept related to my original post: 1) I have a Main View controller (Xcode 4.2 single page template, no storyboard) and to that XIB I added a Nav Bar object and a Toolbar object.  2) I have also added 3 new View via NewFile>UIViewControllerSubclass.  3) To 2 of these new view XIBs (A and B), I have added a Nav bar object.  4)I now need to add a Nav Controller to the Main View Controller XIB and use it to move between Main, A, and B.  Am I stating this correctly? Why is there no Toolbar controller? Thx.

Comment: I think you may have gone a bit wrong there. Again, be very careful when saying things like "I added three views by selecting newFile>UIViewControllerSubclass" because you may be confusing views and view controllers, or at least confusing me! You probably don't need to add navbars to your views as the navbar is controlled by a navigation controller. Start by working out what you app navigation will be - will it have tabs or will the navigation be back and forward like a browser? If it will have tabs, start a new project using the tab bar template. If it has back/forward navigation...

Comment: ...go into your app delegate. In the appDidFinishLaunching method, initialise the window.rootViewController with a UINavigationController instead of the viewController. You'll notice that the UINavigationController init method takes an argument called rootViewController. Use your original view controller as the rootViewController for the navigation controller, and make the navigation controller be the rootViewController for the window. In you nib remove the navbar because the navigationController will now insert that automatically. Same goes for the toolbar...

Comment: ... if you remove the toolbar from your nib, you can set the toolbarHidden property of the navigation controller to NO to show it. Now from within your custom viewController you can set the navigation bar buttons and title using the self.navigationItem.x properties, and you can set the toolbar items using self.toolbarItems property. To display a new view controller use the [self.navigationController pushViewController:] method and pass in an instance of one of the other custom view controller classes that you have created.